# Python Cut Example

Tags: python, cut

I'm looking for a way in python to achieve similar functionality to the unix `cut` utility.  I know I can make a system call and process my data that way but I'd like to make it a bit more "pythonic" and do it with python libraries.

Example text

```
abcde:12345
```

I'd like to delimit on `:` and keep the second field:

```
cut -d':' -f2
```

to produce:

```
12345
```

thoughts?

Comment: What about something like `echo 'abc:123:def:456' | cut -d':' -f1,3`? Is it possible to get fields 1 and 3 within from a single `split()` method, i.e. how to combine indices [1] and [3]?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do:

```
string.split(":")[1]
```

where string is your text

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
'abcde:12345'.split(':')[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
for line in open('data.txt'):
    second_field = line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[1]
```

You can make it more configurable and even write your own with optparse or argparse...let us know more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: That code will include a newline if there are only 2 fields; it's best to do `line.rstrip('\n')` i.e. rstrip *before* split.

Comment: @John thanks, and in the event that it has a different kind of newline, I haven't specified \n

Comment: It can't have have a different form of newline in text mode. You have stripped all/any trailing whitespace, which is overkill. If that is wanted, it should be done on each field of interest.

Comment: @John I didn't realize that about text mode, thank you :) Also, I will fix it.

Answer (score -3):

```
cut -d: -f2
```

Try using this command.

Comment: The question is about how to use a cut operation *in Python*. OP gives the command you posted as the terminal command they wish to replicate *in Python*.

Comment: you have answered linux command. but the question was asked for python.